# У меня есть хранимая функция в базе данных, как мне использовать её в entity framework и вывести результат в представление?

Tags: c#

```
 CREATE FUNCTION ContractCostOfMaterial()     
 RETURNS TABLE 
  AS RETURN(SELECT [Акт приёма-сдачи работ].[номер акта], 
  SUM([Перечень израсходованных материалов].количество * [Перечень израсходованных материалов].[стоимость единицы]) as 'стоимость'
  FROM [Перечень израсходованных материалов], [Акт приёма-сдачи работ]
  WHERE [Перечень израсходованных материалов].[номер акта] = [Акт приёма-сдачи работ].[номер акта] 
  GROUP BY [Акт приёма-сдачи работ].[номер акта])
```

Comment: Какую версию EF используете? Какая СУБД?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под _представлением_? VIEW базы данных? В коде этой вьюхи вызывайте свою функцию и всё.

Comment: Используйте database-first подход, генерируйте контекст по готовой бд.